# Prove $x^{-1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup of $G$.
For $x \in G$, prove $x^{-1}Hx$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We'd like to help you more than by just giving you an answer, so it would be nice to know what you've tried and then start from there.

Comment: This is very much the same kind of question as [your previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/532645/12042): you need to prove the same three things. If $e$ is the identity element of $G$, can you see why $e\in x^{-1}Hx$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I knew how to prove these things I would not be asking on this website. I need a lot of help on my questions

Comment: And I’m more than willing to give it, but unfortunately quite a few folks here are very ready to close questions that don’t contain any indication of what you’ve tried, and I was hoping to help you to forestall that response. It’s also much easier to help when I have a good idea of the level at which I should respond.

Comment: what I tried was completely wrong. I set a in the set and used associativity to cancel the a^-1 and a and get H alone and H was a subgroup of G. I have no idea what I am doing if that helps at all...

Comment: In order to prove a subset of a group is a subgroup, you show that each property of being a subgroup (closure, identity, inverses) is satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You know that you must show that $x^{-1}Hx$ is closed under the group operation, contains the identity element $e$ of $G$, and is closed under taking inverses.

- **Closure:** Let $a,b\in x^{-1}Hx$; you need to show that $ab\in x^{-1}Hx$. There’s only one sensible way to start: what does it actually mean to say that $a$ and $b$ belong to $x^{-1}Hx$? It means that there are $h_a,h_b\in H$ such that $a=x^{-1}h_ax$ and $b=x^{-1}h_bx$. This in turn implies that $ab=(x^{-1}h_ax)(x^{-1}h_bx)=x^{-1}h_a(xx^{-1})h_bx$. Now try to simplify this in a way that proves that $ab\in x^{-1}Hx$. Remember, $H$ isn’t just any old subset of $G$: $H$ is a **subgroup** of $G$.
- **Identity:** You need to show that $e\in x^{-1}Hx$, which means that you need to find some element $h\in H$ such that $e=x^{-1}hx$. You know that $x^{-1}x=e$; what element of $H$ could you squeeze into the middle of that product without changing the result?
- **Inverses:** If $a\in x^{-1}Hx$, you need to show that $a^{-1}\in x^{-1}Hx$ as well. Start just as for closure under the group operation: if $a\in x^{-1}Hx$, there is some $h_a\in H$ such that $a=x^{-1}h_ax$. This certainly implies that $a^{-1}=(x^{-1}h_ax)^{-1}$; what theorem do you know about the inverse of a product that will let you simplify $(x^{-1}h_ax)^{-1}$? There really is only one, and it will give you what you need in order to conclude that $a^{-1}\in x^{-1}Hx$.

Comment: For closure: would you end by stating that hahb = some hn which is an element of H and x^-1hnx is in H?? For Identity: would you set h to 1?   For Inverses: the only theorem I know is (ab)^-1 = b^-1a^-1 but I dont know how that helps

Comment: @user101968: I would indeed: because $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, **it** is closed under the group operation, so $h_ah_b\in H$, and that’s exactly what you need.

Comment: are my inverse and identity parts right as well?

Comment: @user101968: You’re fine with the identity: you know that $e\in H$, so $e=x^{-1}ex\in x^{-1}Hx$. You have the right theorem for dealing with inverses, but you need to extend it a little: $$(abc)^{-1}=\big((ab)c\big)^{-1}=c^{-1}(ab)^{-1}=c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}\;.$$ Now you can apply it to a product of three things.

Comment: so it becomes xhax^-1 and ha^-1 is in H so it a^-1 is contained in x^-1Hx?

Comment: @user101968: Almost: you should get $x^{-1}h_a^{-1}x$, not $xh_a^{-1}x^{-1}$, and you need that, since you need to have the $x^{-1}$ on the left. But yes, once you get that, you’re in business, because $h_a^{-1}\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Prerequisite:
You need to know how to invert expressions of the form $abc$ in a group.  I.e. $(abc)^{-1} = c^{-1} b^{-1} a^{-1}$.  Prove that.

To prove that any subset $H' \subset G$ is a subgroup all you have to do is prove that for all $a,b \in H'$ you have $ab^{-1}\in H'$.

Let $H' = x H x^{-1}$ be as above.  Let $x a x^{-1}, x b x^{-1}$ be two elements from $H'$.  Note that it's okay to represent them that way.  Then $(xb x^{-1})^{-1} = x b^{-1}x^{-1}$.  Multiply together to get:

$$
(x a x^{-1})( x b^{-1} x^{-1}) = x a b^{-1} x^{-1}, \text{ which is in our } H', \text{ since } ab^{-1} \in H.
$$

Then your done.

Note that we implicitly used associativity of the group operation throughout.